# Error when using a Form : Element type is invalid expected a string but got undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have the following error

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in

I have read many post about this error, like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9249) or [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332)
but they all say the same : I incorrectly export my component. But I don't understand what is wrong with my export

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground, Linking, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage} from 'react-native-elements';

type Props = {};
export default class Login extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
        login: '',
   };
  }
  someFunction(){
    Alert.alert("test")
  }

  onPress (){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  }

  checkLogin(login){
    Alert.alert('test');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={require("./images/logo.png")}>
            </Image>
            <FormLabel style={styles.flex1}>enter Login of your Hotel</FormLabel>
            <FormInput 
                //value = {this.state.login}
                onChangeText={login => this.checkLogin({login})}
                //onChangeText={this.checkLogin.bind(login)}
                placeholder='enter your login'
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and App.js :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground, Linking, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation"
import {HomeScreen} from './HomeScreen';
import Display from './Display';
import Login from './Login';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Display: Display,
  Login: Login,
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Login",
  headerMode: 'none', 
}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Do you have an idea of what is wrong ? Error only comes when I use FormInput and FormLabel. If I replace by hello it is displayed

Comment: Where `FormLabel` and `FormInput` come from?

Comment: @Vencovsky: from react-native-elements

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `FormInput` and `FormLabel` were deprecated in v1.0.0-beta.

See here (under **v1.0.0-beta (beta 1) Changes** section) - https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta

You should use `Input` instead of `FormInput` with a `label` property instead of using `FormLabel` component.

```
<FormInput 
   label={"Login"} />
```