# Need some help for Log In Form

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Can someone help me to figure out where is my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import HomeScreen from '../components/HomeScreen';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {FormLabel, FormInput} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {email:'', password:'', error:'', loading: false};
  }

  onLoginPress(){
    this.setState({error:'', loading: true});
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({error:'', loading: false})
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    })
    .catch(() =>{
      this.setState({error:'Authentication failed', loading: false});
    })
  }

  onSignUpPress(){
    this.setState({error:'', loading: true});
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({error:'', loading: false})
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    })
    .catch(() =>{
      this.setState({error:'Authentication failed', loading: false});
    })
  }

  renderButtonOrLoading(){
    if(this.state.loading){
      return <Text> Loading </Text>
    }
    return <View>
      <Button
      onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)} 
      title='Login'/> 
       <Button
      onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}
      title='Sign Up'/>
    </View>
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Label> Email </Label>
    <Input
    label={"Login"}
    value={this.state.email}
    placeholder='john@gmail.com' 
    onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}/>
    <Label> Password </Label>
    <Input
    label={"Login"}
    value={this.state.password}
    secureTextEntry
    placeholder='********'
    onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}/>
    <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
    {this.renderButtonOrLoading()}
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

Here is the error:

[image: error]

Comment: please show the imports in your file

Comment: Also it's bad practice to access this state directly in that way. Suggest you use `setState()` instead.

Comment: okay you can see my imports now

Comment: Except the section from firebase. That's all

Comment: This `this.state({error:'', loading: false})` is wrong. Change all `this.state()` to `this.setState()` and also see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Same error, check my updated code

Comment: @YoanIvanov : Everything in your code is looking OK , Only thing suspicious is HomeScreen . Just check out if everything is right on HomeScreen especially export statement.

Comment: what is your version of `react-native-elements`? There are no components named `FormLabel` and `FormInput` in the latest version

Comment: Oh whit what can I replace them

Comment: Check the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595795/error-when-using-a-form-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-but-got-unde/55608881#55608881

Comment: Let me try whit that, and let you if the problem is solved

Comment: Mmm weird. Let me do some more looking.

Comment: Check my answer, managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Input} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class FormExample extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Input
        label={"Login"}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So I just have to put a label inside Input ?

Comment: Yeah put it as a property of the input

Comment: Sorry :D, but is this a new Input or I have to put it in mine, because I have one for email and one for password. Or in both ?

Comment: Just edit and put "UPDATE" at the end with your new code

Comment: You can check it

Comment: Ah so ```Label``` doesn't exist as a component, but is replaced by the 'label' property on the ```Input``` component. So just remove your ```Label``` components and put the text you want as the label in the ```Input``` (like in my example)

Comment: Okay it's working now but why I'm getting "Authentication failed" when I press Sign Up ?

Comment: Can't help you there unfortunately. I would suggest asking a separate question with that as the topic then someone with more knowledge of firebase can help you out. Glad I could help with your original issue though. Please upvote my answer if you're happy :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all

Comment: It's a pleasure!